# Numpad enter key doesn't work in Python program

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, enter, numpad

I have a Python program running on Raspberry Pi 3 (Raspbian version 10) and I need to do all operations only with Numpad. Everything works fine, but NUMPAD ENTER KEY doesn't work. When I want to enter my input via numpad enter, nothing happens. Does someone know how to fix it?

I tried this but doesn't work

```
number.bind("<KP_Enter>",keyTray)
```

Comment: You need to check what key is actually getting sent by the numpad Enter key.  You can google search to find an online keyboard ghosting test.  (Microsoft has one here: https://www.microsoft.com/applied-sciences/projects/anti-ghosting-demo)

Answer (score 0):

Try binding `<Return>` instead of `<KP_Enter>`:

```
number.bind("<Return>", keyTray)
```